# <div> Sections won't show up

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so, I am very new to javascript and mildy so in CSS and HTML. I'm working on a portfolio and my separate  sections (for contact, illustrations, projects) were with display:hidden. I used a function for each section that I wanted to hide and display correspondingly on the screen and they were working fine up until I made some changes in the overall code. Now, two of the sections won't show up. Here is my code:

```js
function out() {
  document.getElementById('trim').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('baby').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('mba').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('blab').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('vdeo').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('outros').style.display = 'block'
}
```

```html
  <nav>
  <p id="trab">Trabalhos</p> <!--style=" text-decoration: overline;"-->
  <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <li id="outros"><button onclick="out()">Outros Projetos</button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
   
    <!-- Outros Projetos -->
    <div id="outros" class="otro" style="margin-left:230px; padding-top:200px; padding-right:200px; position: fixed; top:0; display:none;">
      <h5><a href="front.html" target="_blank"> fsf◹</a></h5>
      <p style="font-size:16px;">Duo, som/vídeo</p>
      <br> <!-- -->
      <h5>Book of Isi</h5>
      <p style="font-size:16px;">(Projeto em construção)</p>
    </div>
```

This is just one of the two cases that won't work, the other 4  sections are appearing just fine using the same method.

Comment: Hi, your code works fine can you briefly describe the problem...... ?

Comment: This section, along with another one, were showing up just fine until I added another section, and so, another button and another function. The idea was that all these sections, that ocuppy the center of the page, would show up only if I clicked the proper menu button for them on the page, and the other ones get hidden. If I click the designated button, it just shows up as if there were no content whastoever. However, if I change display:block; right on the <div>, it does show up, BUT, it's not the desired effect, since all the other content get juxtaposed with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw what I did wrong here, now it's working fine:

I had a different section commented out (video section), because I wasn't using it. But I forgot to delete the "document.getElementById" that redirected to it from all the functions. I deleted it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this inside your `out()` function

```
document.getElementById('outros').style.display = 'block !important'
```

Comment: Tried it, but won't get visible. It's really weird because the same function was working just fine until I added another section. Maybe it's too much content I added? I've got no idea.

Comment: What are the id's for the other sections. If you have the same id for all the sections I don't believe that will work

Comment: Different id's.

Comment: Could you edit your full question to include all relevant code? I think having one section is hard to find out where the problem might be

Comment: Done. Sorry for the mess!

Answer (score 0):

Try inline as value

```
document.getElementById('outros').style.display = 'inline'
```